# Why use "viewWithTag" with "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

can someone please explain why you should use `viewWithTag` to get subviews (e.g. `UILabel` etc) from a cell in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?

Some background info: I've got a custom `UITableViewCell` with a couple of `UILabel`s in it (I've reproduced a simple version of this below). These labels are defined in the associated NIB file and are declared with `IBOutlet`s and linked back to the custom cell's controller class. In the tableview's `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, I'm doing this:

```
CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellId"];
if (customCell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id oneObject in nib)
        if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            customCell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;
}

customCell.firstLabel.text = @"Hello";
customCell.secondLabel.text = @"World!";

return customCell;
```

Everything works fine. However from the tutorials I've seen, it looks like when changing the labels' values I should be doing this instead:

```
UILabel *firstLabel = (UILabel *)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:555];
firstLabel.text = @"Hello";

UILabel *secondLabel = (UILabel *)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:556];
secondLabel.text = @"World!";
```

(The labels' tag values have been set in the NIB).

Can someone tell me which method is preferred and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've realised that it's useful to retrieve elements using "viewWithTag" if the elements were added to the cell programmatically (i.e. not defined in a NIB and hooked-up via IBOutlets)—this prevents multiple labels etc. to be created for each instance of the cell.

Comment: Usually you should use a UITableViewCell subclass over the quick and dirty viewWithTag method.

Answer (score 14):

`viewWithTag:` is just a quick and dirty way to pull out child views without having to set up IBOutlet properties on the parent, or even without having to create a UITableViewCell subclass.

For *very simple* cases this is an acceptable solution, that's what `viewWithTag:` was intended for. However if you are going to reuse that cell a lot or you want it to have a more developer-friendly interface then you will want to subclass and use real properties as in your first example.

So use `viewWithTag:` if it's a very simple cell you designed in IB with no subclass and with just a couple of labels. Use a cell subclass with real properties for anything more substantial.

Answer (score 4):

For me , viewWithTag is a God given. First of all : treating all views in a loop like taskinoor said is really easy. Also , I personally prefer this way because if I take a look on the code and want to see what happens with a view , I simply search for the tag. It's used everywhere the view is handled. Opposed to the xib approach where you have to look in the code and xib too. Also , if you have an offscreen view in a xib , you might oversee it. 
I found a lot of xibs made by other programmers that were FULL with lots and lots of views. Some hidden , some offscreen , couldn't tell which is which since there were all overlapping.
In those cases , I think xibs are bad. They are not easy to read anymore. 
I prefer everything made in code.

But if you decide to work with tags, remember to avoid hard-coding any tag. Instead make a list of #define definitions to keep the code clean and readable.

Answer (score 1):

I always hook subviews to properties of my UITableViewCell subclass via IBOutlets, as you have done.  I can't think of any good reason to use viewWithTag.

Answer (score 0):

From UITableViewCell Class Reference: "The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell."  Keep it simple, clear out the content view.  This makes no assumptions about custom cell classes, no casts, no class inspection:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
if (cell != nil)
{
    NSArray* contentSubViews = [cell.contentView subviews];
    for (UIView* viewToRemove in contentSubViews)
    {
        [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewWithTag:` allows styling **without creating a custom subclass** of `UITableViewCell`.

You can assign a tag and reuse identifier to a prototype `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder, then dequeue and modify the view with that tag within the implementation of your `UITableViewController`, without creating a custom class for that cell or creating IBOutlets for the cell's subviews.

In some cases, the simplicity of a cell makes a custom class feel like overkill. `viewWithTag:` allows you to add custom text and image to a cell in the Storyboard, then set those customizations via code, without adding extra class files to your Xcode project.